# How to hide get_theme_mod if field empty

Tags: php, get-theme-mod

I'm using: get_theme_mod to show various pieces of info from the theme customizer, in the following format:

```
<a href=" <?php get_theme_mod( $name, $default ) ?> ">This is the link</a>
```

I would like to hide the whole line if that particular customizer field is empty.

What could I wrap around the anchor to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

```
$value = get_theme_mod( $name, $default );
if ($value !== $default) { 
?>
   <a href=" <?php echo $value; ?> ">This is the link</a>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Otto! Funny you answered, as it's from your customizer tutorial I'm following. Where abouts would I place this code? In functions.php?

Comment: Wherever the code you had above is, most likely your template.

Answer (score 3):

Looking for an answer to displaying default text in place of a customizer set heading. In a funny roundabout way, thepost by @Otto gave me the idea of checking for an empty string.

```
<?php if( get_theme_mod( 'tcx_portfolio_intro') == '' ) : ?>
<div class="intro">
<h2><?php echo ('nothing here yet'); ?></h2>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of your default value in the customizer setting, you could just compare the theme modification value to an empty string:

```
<?php    
$link = get_theme_mod( $name );
if ($link !== '' ) { 
?>
   <a href="<?php echo $link; ?> ">This is the link</a>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if is not null we will show the content:

```
if (get_theme_mod($name, '') != NULL){
  // the content to show   
}
```

If is null we will show nothing.